# How to use sed to get the required output?

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix, sed

This is my string:

```
<InstalledVersion Name="xyz" version="5" identifier="6.3.0.00.267" supportData="A002-IBY03" supportRelease="6.3" versionCode="xyz/abc/267"></InstalledVersion>
```

What i want output from this is as 203. The last character of A002 and last two character of IBY03. Thus the output being 203.
I am using `sed 's/.*supportData="A\([0-9]\+[-][A-Z]\+[0-9]\+\)".*/\1/' | cut -c3,8,9'.`
This gives me the correct output but I was wondering if I can directly do it through sed .
Any help  would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
s='<InstalledVersion Name="xyz" version="5" identifier="6.3.0.00.267" supportData="A002-IBY03" supportRelease="6.3" versionCode="xyz/abc/267">'

sed -E 's/.*supportData="[^"]*([0-9])-[^"]*([0-9]{2})".*/\1\2/' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
203
```

Comment: Thanks
This is working but not on my whole string somehow. My whole string being  
'<InstalledVersion Name="xyz" version="5" identifier="6.3.0.00.101" supportData="A002-IBY03" supportRelease="6.3" versionCode="xyz/abc/267">'

Comment: Done. please check

Comment: Really sorry to edit the string again this is working just a minor change in string would really appreciate your help

Comment: I tested with your updated input and this command still outputs `203`

Comment: I am getting 203 and </InstalledVersion>

Comment: There is a `.*` in the end also if you note. [See this working demo](http://ideone.com/CTOKM7)

Comment: **Make sure you have `</InstalledVersion>` in the same line not on the next line.**

Comment: My bad I guess it is on the next line. can it still be done ?

Comment: Try: `sed -E '/<InstalledVersion/s/.*supportData="[^"]*([0-9])-[^"]*([0-9]{2})".*/\1\2/;2d' <<< "$s"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110468/discussion-between-mohit-arora-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ var='supportData="A002-IBY03"'
$ sed -r 's/.*([0-9])-.*([0-9][0-9])"/\1\2/' <<<$var
203
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$ echo '<InstalledVersion Name="xyz" version="5" identifier="6.3.0.00.101" supportData="A002-IBY03" supportRelease="6.3" versionCode="xyz/abc/267">' | sed -r 's/^.*supportData=".{3}([0-9])-.{3}([0-9]{2}).*$/\1\2/'
203
$
```